# How to add other plugin in my custom RCP E4?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I developed a RCP e4 using vogella tutorial 
In my RCP e4 application I need to include other plug in.
How can I do?
An alternative may be to insert in the functionality "install new software," and allow the installation directly from my custom RCP.
But I don't find a tutorial on how to include this functionality.

Suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a plugin you have written or a third party plugin? Is your 'xxx.product' file plugins based or features based?

Comment: It is a third part plugin and my 'xxx.product' file is feature based

Comment: Is the plugin designed for e4? Many existing plugins use the 3.x compatibility layer and won't work in a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new abaut eclipse-rcp and I thought that with functionality "Install new software.." in my custom RCP E4 was possible to insert any third-party plugin.

Comment: A pure e4 RCP does not include a lot of the plugins required by the older 3.x style RCP plugins. Consequently you can't use plugins that depend on that code. You can still write a 3.x style RCP which will allow the old plugins to be used.

Answer (score 0):

To add an existing plugin to your RCP add the plugin to your Target Platform ('Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform').

Then add the plugin to your feature.xml (or create a new feature.xml for the plugin and include that in your .product file).

Note that many existing plugins are designed for the Eclipse 3.x compatibility layer and won't work in a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to develop an application "eclipse-like" using two third-party plugins and integrating other function (my plugin). I thought that the best solution is  1) to start from an empty RCP application; 2) include third-party plugin; 3) include my plugin.